# Adjust new swap memory

Tags: swap

Currently, my system have 2 GB swap memory, in the following structure-

/dev/sda1   --linux-swap   --
/dev/sda2   --ext4         -- System installation
 
Unallocated --unallocated  --

[image]

Now I want to increase the swap memory. I have **very poor knowledge in ubuntu**. I'm trying to add more swap memory in following way-
/dev/sda1   --linux-swap   --
/dev/sda2   --ext4         -- System installation
 
New Partition#1   --linux-swap   --
Unallocated --unallocated  --
[image]

Will it work as swap memory for my system? is there any way to merge both the swap memory into one, like in windows MiniPartionWizard partion do restructure without loosing any data.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create the swap  like in the second screenshot.
- Then right-click on the `/dev/sda1` and select swap-off.And then delete the partition.
- Now right-click on the swap(newly created) and select swap-on.

If you want to add the 1 Gb of unallocated space to 10 GB swap partition,then you need to boot gparted live-disk or ubuntu live-disk.

- Boot gparted or ubuntu live disk,install gparted and then open it.
- Now right-click on the `/dev/sda2` partition and select Resize option.Then drag the slider to the extreme left to move the unallocated space below `/dev/sda2`.So that you can add the 1gb space to the 10 gb swap partition.
- Right click on the linux-swap partition to increase its size.

Comment: you doesn't loss any datas by doing the above.

Comment: I have created 2nd swap memory of 10GB space and made it swapon without making previous swapoff. Now on system monitor it's displaying 11.9GB of swap memory. Hope I've done. One question-keeping both of them swapon will gong to create any problem?

Comment: it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: 10GiB of paging? What are you trying to do? If you reguarly use more then 1GB of swap then consider buying more memory, not increasing swap. (except if ram is maxed out and you do not mind waiting a few extra weeks for a program to run).

Comment: Hennes,i also think that 10 gb was unnecessary,but op wants to increase its swap partition size.

Comment: @Hennes -actually I'm going to add total 6GB RAM. fFrom this portal I have got that 9 GB (=6 x 1.5) swap memory is required for my system.

Comment: no longer. Way back when we used SWAP and program were mapped to the swap and all RAM was cache we used to have a rule of SWAP being main RAM x2 or bigger. This is no longer true. Today all systems *page*. It might still be called a swap file and fstabn will still show 'swap' as filesystem, but the methods behind it have changed as have the sizes.

Comment: @Hennes, Avinash- can you please suggest me, what should be ideal amount of swap memory if my system had 6GB of RAM.

Comment: If does not simply depend on you main memory. How much RAM do you typically use? (Get that as real RAM). How much do you rarely use on top of that? (e.g. usually 4-5 GB, but once per month 7GiB when recompiling QT. In that case get 2+ GiB-ish swap (8 is 6+2, and round up for some spare). In almost all cases this means swap never needs to be larger than 2-3 GiB.